# Extract portion of retrieved string in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

"substitute(index(importhtml("https://site_name.com/quote.ashx?t="&E14,"table",10),8,2),"","")" returns a text value; "'*0.72 (13.28%)*'"

The return value can vary in length.

I need to extract either just the 0.72 or 13.28 so I can then convert to numeric format.

Comment: Try the SPLIT function: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en. I.e. SPLIT("0.72 (13.28%)", " ") => ["0.72", "(13.28%)"]. This works if there will always be a space separating your values. Otherwise, you can try using regex as another approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Extracting only 1 value out of 2 from indefinite length of string

Based on your question I assume that you only want to get 1 value every 2 values being returned by the importhtml function. I would suggest using this formula to extract it

```
=FILTER(SPLIT(A1, " "), ISERROR(SEARCH("-", SPLIT(A1, " "))))
```

It will return 1 row only, if you are looking to have it as 1 column instead please enclose it on a transpose function.

### Output:

[image]

### References:

[Split Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en)

[Filter](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en&sjid=8327777646214599768-AP)

[Search](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094154?hl=en&sjid=8327777646214599768-AP)

Comment: Please let me know if you have any further questions. By the way this formula assumes the format based on your given example. You can change the  A1 into the data on importhtml or your formula to get the values. If this answers your question please feel free to accept the answer provided this way other community members will know that their question have answers too.

Comment: Thank you Babanana.  The actual source returns  *0.72 (13.28%)* including the asterisk at the front and end.    I changed the formula to:  (mid(FILTER(SPLIT(AL20, " "), ISERROR(SEARCH("-", SPLIT(AL20, " ")))),2,5)) and get the result I need.